# How do I pronounce the "Taol" coin from Waterdeep?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, waterdeep-dragon-heist, pronunciation

In the city of Waterdeep, there's a coin called a "Taol" worth 2 gp. I find the description of the coin in Waterdeep: Dragon Heist on page 169, but it's not on the pronunciation guide on page 4. I'm trying to figure out how I would pronounce it in my games. Is it "TAY-all"? "TOW-ull" (like "towel")? So does it somehow all slur together in one syllable like "tail" (rhyming with "[gaol](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gaol)")? Is there some "official" pronunciation, or does every group just fend for themselves?

Comment: Even [this comprehensive compilation of official pronunciations](https://www.enworld.org/threads/d-d-pronunciation-guide.661505/) doesn't list a pronunciation for "taol"... Also, [Ed Greenwood describes the correct spelling here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/11/16/the-brass-waterdeep-coin-its-called-a-taol-or-toal-which-spelling-pronunciation-do-you-prefer/), but not exactly the pronunciation. (...Though I guess it kind of hints at it?)

Comment: You could [tweet Ed Greenwood](https://twitter.com/TheEdVerse) and get his response. His statements are usually considered official by Forgotten Realms fans. That's probably the closest you'd get to a canonical answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Quadratic Wizard suggested, I sent a Twitter message to Ed Greenwood (creator of Forgotten Realms and basically the authority on such things), who was kind enough to [reply](https://twitter.com/TheEdVerse/status/1166371091658477568):

> **"TAY-ole."**

Comment: I always pronounced it to rhyme with *towel* so thanks for taking the effort.